# Trouble seeing Selenium exception error message

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am adding Try/Except clauses to my Selenium script but am having trouble seeing the error messages when I execute this in PyCharm.  The script blows up but no error is found.

I purposely changed the XPATH so it would fail, and I tried a couple ways but neither of these 2 methods actually print the error message to the screen.  Any ideas?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def choose_dress(self):
        try:
            self.dresses = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((
                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="block_top_menu"]/ul/li[2]/b')))
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        else:
            print('NO ELEMENT FOUND!')


def choose_dress(self):
    try:
        self.dresses = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 5).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="block_top_menu"]/ul/li[2]/b')))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('NO ELEMENT FOUND!')
    else:
        self.dresses.click()
```

Comment: Try this `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: Does `expected_conditions` ever return a `NoSuchElementException`?